# which Layout manager in java is better for achieve the GUI I want?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, layout-manager

I am new to Java GUI and find a problem about choosing right layout manager to achieve the layout I want. Below is what I get so far and what I want to achieve:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYKzN.jpg)

[image]

[image]

And here is what I did:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjO3w.jpg)

[image]

I used BoxLayout in JPanel(1)~(9).

used boxlayout with Y-axis in (1),(2),(3),(6),(7)

used boxlayout with X-axis in (4),(5)

the relation of panels(1)~(9) is :

(4) contains (1),(2),(3).

(7) contains (4) (5) (6).

Hopes someone will kindly give me some advice.Thanks.

Comment: I would use gridbaglayout with 5 columns and use multiple columns for different elements. The tables will span columns 1-2 and 4-5. The "Please select one..." part and buttons on bottom would span columns 2-4. I'm not sure what you are using now, but this could be only a problem of anchoring?

Comment: I often use [combinations of layout managers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) rather than try to find the perfect 'one' layout manager..

Comment: Also it's handy to use layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556)..

Comment: What is the layout of 7? Try `BorderLayout`, with 4 in `NORTH`, 5 in `CENTER` and 6 in `SOUTH`.  Panel 6 looks more like a `GridLayout(1, 2)`.